# Should I increase versions after a release or with every commit

Tags: version-control, version, semantic-versioning

We want to implement semantic versioning in our process, we are in version 1.0.0, and we have added two new functions. We will deliver these functions soon.

The question is: should we name our next version 1.1 or should we name it 1.2 because we have created two new functions.

In general, if we add **n** new functions, should we increment by **n** the minor component of the version, or we only increment by one in each delivery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version does not depend on how many functions
you have written in that particular release.
If your current version is 1.0.0 ,then
it should be 1.0.1 or 1.1 depend upon your
naming rule that you have put for your
product and dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

There is no absolut right solution to version numbers.

The way most people i know do it is by increasing it on every version they plan on making available.

Microsoft themselves for example use the "major, minor, build, and revision" semantic for their version numbers. Just don't change up the way you do your version numbers after deciding on one. Because then they become useless :-)

Comment: I can only mark one answer as the right one, but you are right, thank you for your answer.